# How to check if a column contains list

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["a", "b", "c", ["a", "b"]]})
```

I have a dataframe like this, and I want to find the rows that contains list in that column. I tried value_counts() but it tooks so long and throws error at the end. Here is the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.map_locations()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
Exception ignored in: 'pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._call_map_locations'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1709, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.map_locations
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
c         1
a         1
[a, b]    1
b         1
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

For bigger dataframes this tooks forever.

Here is how the desired output look like:

```
col1
c       1
b       1
[a,b]   1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists are mutable, they cannot be compared, so you can neither count the values nor set them as index. You would need to convert to `tuple` <del>or `set`</del> (thanks @CameronRiddell) to be able to count:

```
df['col1'].apply(lambda x: tuple(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
c         1
b         1
a         1
(a, b)    1
Name: col1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: A `set` is also mutable, wouldn't it have to be a `frozenset` if they wanted something set-like?

Comment: @CameronRiddell That was silly of me. Thanks for pointing out. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Iterate on rows and check type of `obj` in column by this condition: `type(obj) == list`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["a", "b", "c", ["a", "b"]]})

for ind in df.index:
   print (type(df['col1'][ind]) == list)
```

And here is the result:

```
False
False
False
True
```